# How to split a file into chunks with 1000 lines in each chunk in Bash?

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I have a file that is 6200 lines long that looks like:

```
  chrom chromStart chromEnd score           a          a.1
1  chr1     834359   867552     4 0.020979021 0.0000000000
2  chr1    1880283  1940830     9 0.075757576 0.0000000000
3  chr1    1960387  2064958    13 0.115093240 0.0006596306
4  chr1    2206040  2249092     5 0.019230769 0.0000000000
5  chr1    2325759  2408930    11 0.021296885 0.0080355001
```

I need to break the file into files that are 1000 lines long. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want lines 1..1000 in one file, and 1001..2000 in another, and so on, or do you want just lines 1000..2000 in another file?  Both are doable (easily doable), but you do it differently (`sed` vs `split`). Also, do you need to preserve the heading line in each output file?

Comment: Classic case of the question title being different from the actual question.  XY problem.

Comment: @Joanthan Leffler, 1..1000 in one file. 1001...2000 in another. I just made the title because if someone answered that. I could go from there and answer my own problem

Comment: Have you put any effort into trying to solve this yourself?  If so, please indicate what you have tried.  Lack of demonstrated effort on your part makes it likely that this question will be down-voted and closed.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a case for the POSIX [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) command:

```
split -l 1000 file-to-be-split prefix.
```

This will split the 'file to be split' into files with 1000 lines each (except the last, of course), and the names will start with `prefix.` and will end with `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, ...